# Why does my NSArray have zero objects?

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, nsarray

I'm trying to add some UIImage objects to an array, but it's not working. I tried adding the images to an NSArray and for some reason, the array isn't holding anything?

Here is my code:

```
UIImage *a = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"A.jpg"];
UIImage *b = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"B.jpg"];
UIImage *c = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"C.jpg"];
UIImage *d = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"D.jpg"];
UIImage *e = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"E.jpg"];
UIImage *f = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"F.jpg"];

self.imageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:a, b, c, d, e, f, nil];

int firstArrayCount = [self.array count];   
NSLog(@"%d objects in array 1", firstArrayCount);

int secondArrayCount = [self.imageArray count];
NSLog(@"%d objects in array 2", secondArrayCount);
```

Comment: Are you sure that none of the images are `nil`?

Comment: [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"A" ofType:@".jpg"]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIImage *a = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"A" ofType:@".jpg"]];
UIImage *b = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"B" ofType:@".jpg"]];
UIImage *c = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"C" ofType:@".jpg"]];
UIImage *d = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"D" ofType:@".jpg"]];
UIImage *e = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"E" ofType:@".jpg"]];
UIImage *f = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"F" ofType:@".jpg"]];

NSArray *imageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:a, b, c, d, e, f, nil];

int secondArrayCount = [imageArray count];
NSLog(@"%d objects in array 2", secondArrayCount);
```

**OR**

```
UIImage *a = [UIImage imageNamed:@"A.jpg"];
UIImage *b = [UIImage imageNamed:@"B.jpg"];
UIImage *c = [UIImage imageNamed:@"C.jpg"];
UIImage *d = [UIImage imageNamed:@"D.jpg"];
UIImage *e = [UIImage imageNamed:@"E.jpg"];
UIImage *f = [UIImage imageNamed:@"F.jpg"];

NSArray *imageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:a, b, c, d, e, f, nil];

int secondArrayCount = [imageArray count];
NSLog(@"%d objects in array 2", secondArrayCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try loading the images with [UIImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed%3a)'s `+imageNamed:` instead. For example,

```
UIImage *a = [UIImage imageNamed:@"A"];
```

Check that all these images have been added to your project, and not just that they appear in the XCode pane. Failing that, and only assuming this code is not all in the same scope, check that your `NSArray` property is retain and not assign.